# User Location error

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

Hi I have this code to zoom in on the users location.

```
-(IBAction)getLocation{

mapview.showsUserLocation = YES;

MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.0} };
region.center = mapview.userLocation.coordinate;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.1f;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.1f;

[mapview setRegion:region animated:YES];

}
```

On the first press of the button the map moves to coordinate 0,0, however on any subsequent presses it works as it should and takes the map to the users location. I cannot figure out why it does not work on the first go but works everytime after that??

Comment: Have you considered `NSLog()` or using the debugger?

Comment: I did but I still couldn't see what was causing the problem. It would just tell me that the users location is 0.00000, 0.00000 initially then on subsequent presses it would give the correct coordinates

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
- (IBAction)showCurrentLocation:(id)sender {
self.mapview.showsUserLocation=YES;
self.mapview.delegate = self;
[self.mapview setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];
```

}